# Create post from form with image

Tags: posts, php, attachments, front-end

I found this wonderdul script that @Bainternet here at Wordpress Answers created, that makes it possible to attach images into posts from a html form..

I tried to combine in into my "html form to post" script.. I does create a post as draft in the backend.. but the image does not show up, and it doesn't show in "media" ..

This is @Bainternet script/answer,
[Submit post and upload image from front-end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/submit-post-and-upload-image-from-front-end)

This is mine,

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
$post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
$post_category = 'fashion';
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

$new_post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $user->ID, 
      'post_category' => array($post_category),
      'post_content' => $post_content,
      'post_title' => $post_title,
      'post_status' => 'draft'
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);


        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
            }   
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }


// This will redirect you to the newly created post
$post = get_post($post_id);
wp_redirect( 'http://domain.com' );
}      
?>      

<form method="post" action=""> 
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title" value="heading"/><br>
<input type="text" name="post_url" size="45" id="input-url" value="Url"/><br>
<input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"><br>
<textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/> <br>
<input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your form tag missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so try changing:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

to:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and as a side note, if you want to redirect to the newly created post change:

```
wp_redirect( 'http://domain.com' );
```

to:

```
wp_redirect( get_permalink($post_id));
exit();
```

Update:
From the comments i understand that want the image to show inside the content, well that is a different thing but not that hard,

change:

```
if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }
```

to:

```
if ($attach_id > 0){
    $post = get_post($post_id,'ARRAY_A');
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id );
    $image_tag = '<img src="'.$image[0].'" width="'.$image[1].'" height="'.$image[2].'" />';

    //add image above the content
    $post['post_content'] = $image_tag . $post['post_content'];

    //add image under the content
    //$post['post_content'] = $post['post_content'] . $image_tag;

    $post_id =  wp_update_post( $post );
}
```

Comment: saw that i missed out on the enctype.. when i tried it afterwards the form just keeps loading and loading.. and i'm just uploading a 500kb image.. get's stuck in just loading.. thanks for answering by the way! :)

Comment: does the post get generated?

Comment: Works now.. but the image doesn't attach in the post.. but i can see the image in the upload folder and media gallery.. is there any easy way to attach it as "large"? has it anything to do with _thumbnail_id tag?

Comment: you want to insert the image to the post's content?

Comment: yes! is that a total different thing?

Comment: or should i just use wp_update_post insted of update_post_meta..

Comment: yep totally different, any way i updated my answer

Comment: @Bainternet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/790/discussion-between-dennist-and-bainternet)

Comment: I hope you can see what i wrote in the chat room.. Big thanks! you are golden!

Comment: How can i choose to insert the large image.. now it shows the thumbnail by default.

Comment: It runs really slow to, does it have anything to do with file permissions?

Comment: you can get the large image by adding 'large' to the [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) call.

Comment: as for how fast it runs that's all about the severs settings

Comment: I now know why this script is slow, it only works when i'm logged into the WP admin. Is there a way to make it work if you're not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that needs the same script.

What it does,
A simple html form uploads a image and some text to wordpress and media gallery and creates a post as draft from the content posted. And redirects you to the created post for preview.

Big thanks to @Bainternet

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
$post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
$post_category = 'todays_post';
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

$new_post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $user->ID, 
      'post_category' => array($post_category),
      'post_content' => $post_content,
      'post_title' => $post_title,
      'post_status' => 'draft'
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);


        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
            }   
        }
if ($attach_id > 0){
    $post = get_post($post_id,'ARRAY_A');
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id, 'large' );
    $image_tag = '<p><img src="'.$image[0].'" width="'.$image[1].'" height="'.$image[2].'" /></p>';

    //add image under the content
    $post['post_content'] = $image_tag . $post['post_content'];

    //add image above the content
    //$post['post_content'] = $post['post_content'] . $image_tag;

$post_id =  wp_update_post( $post );
}


// This will redirect you to the newly created post
$post = get_post($post_id);
wp_redirect( get_permalink($post_id));
exit();
}      
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title" value="heading"/><br>
<input type="text" name="post_url" size="45" id="input-url" value="Url"/><br>
<input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"><br>
<textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/> <br>
<input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and when I try, nothing happens. I am not using the image yet, I have only been trying to get the form to make a new post. It seems that the form variables are empty though.

I used a var_dump to check and there is nothing there from my form. The code above does not work for me in the latest version of wordpress. I had to modify it to this

```
$my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_title'] = "My Post"
    $my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post.';
    $my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_author']   = 1;
    $my_post['post_category'] = array(9);
```

This is how I did my testing and it does work this way, only post category doesn't work with a slug which could be a problem. Anytime I try to replace post_title with $_POST['name'] the code fails. Here is my form

```
<form action=" " method="post" name="reservations" id="reservations" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <table width="474" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="reserve">
        <tr>
                            <td class="formInput"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
```