# Front end post submission form with duplicate type fields

Tags: posts, front-end

Here is the simple front end post submission form code

```
<?php $postTitle = $_POST['post_title'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submit)){

    global $user_ID;

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $postTitle,
        'post_content' => $post,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_category' => array(0)
    );

    wp_insert_post($new_post);

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post_title">Post Title</label></td>
    <td><input name="post_title" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post">Post</label></td>
    <td><input name="post" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Its working. But can anyone give me some sample code for "Add another image" type custom fields.

### Update:

Hi i'm using [magic fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields-2/) plugin. I have a custom field called "products image". This is the custom field id "products_image'. That plugin uses meta table to store its custom fields values. I would like to have "Add another image" button in the form. So the users can upload additional product images

Thanks

Comment: No validation...?

Comment: No i'll deal with validation later. As of now i would like to know how to add duplicate type fields.

Comment: Where are you adding the first image that you want to add ANOTHER image?

Comment: @m0r7if3r Hi i'm using magic fields plugin. I have a custom field called "products image". This is the custom field id "products_image'.  That plugin uses meta table to store its custom fields values. I would like to have "Add another image" button in the form. So the users can upload additional product images.

Comment: I don't see the code for that in your question...

Comment: @Viruthagiri Honestly: I'm at the end with your Q. You got 58 Qs so far and still don't know how to write a complete Q? Plus: You don't update your Q, so later readers have to go through comments? To sum it up: Don't expect me answering anyone of your upcoming Qs.

Comment: @m0r7if3r I just wanted to keep the question simple. You asked more details about it. Thats why i explained everything in the comment.

Comment: @kaiser I'm not sure what you mean `I don't know how to write a complete Q?`If you are talking about my english then i'm really sorry.This is the knowledge i have. `You dont update your Q, so later readers have to go through comments?`You asked me to update my last question. I updated it as you asked. Here m0r7if3r asked a question in the comment. So i given more information about what i'm trying to do. `To sum it up: Don't expect me answering anyone of your upcoming Qs` You could walk away without saying anything.But you didn't. Now don't you think its little bit rude when you post like this?

Comment: _»You could walk away without saying anything. But you didn't.«_ I have _hope_. My weakest point. _»You don't know how to write Q«_ --> You didn't provide the needed information, which shouldn't happen after asking _that many_ Qs. Then you get asked for it and don't update your Q. Why?? I mean do you expect later readers to read every comment (like this one) on every Q related to their problem? Honestly? Please learn how to ask and - in case - update your Q so that it becomes part of a valuable source for other people searching for help. And learn it _fast_.

Comment: @kaiser Ok I'll update my questions in the future as you said. I'm really sorry. And one more thing you should give the user a warning before you get angry. By the way i updated this question too.  I hope now it makes sense. If you found any other question that need to be updated let me know. I'll update it too.

Comment: A last note: If you are using plugins, then should always link to their respective download url. That way no one has to search for it when she/he needs to look at the code when answering your Q.

Comment: @kaiser Ok i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11928/2487) and at to store the image as a custom field replace:

```
update_post_meta($new_post,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
```

with what ever name you have for you custom field ex:

```
update_post_meta($new_post,'products_image',$attach_id);
```