# Upload and attach to a post multiple image files

Tags: uploads, attachments, front-end

In a front end form I have a 'multiple' input field for uploading and attaching images to a post and a processing script (from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11928/25187)). I expect that will be uploaded and attached all files that I have selected, but this doesn't happens. Is uploaded and attached only the last selected file (in alphabetical order). When I check the $_FILES array with `var_dump($_FILES)` I see only one file there. **How can I upload and attach to a post multiple files at once?**

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<form id="frontpost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <input type="file" multiple name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
    ...
</form>

<?php return ob_get_clean(); }
```

and a processing script:

```
if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}

if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
        }
        media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
    }   
}
```

Comment: If files are not being sent to the server then it is an HTML question, not a wordpress one....

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add brackets to the `name` of your multiple input form element for PHP to interpret it as an array.

```
<input type="file" multiple name="thumbnail[]" id="thumbnail">
```

You'll then get an array named 'thumbnail' with 5 arrays within it. See [this comment on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240) for a breakdown of the structure.

**Edit**: Notice the difference in what is returned for a single vs a multiple file input. Here's an example with two form fields, one a single file upload and the other a multiple.

```
<pre>
<?php if ($_FILES) {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
</pre>

<form id="frontpost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="single">
    <input type="file" multiple name="multiple[]">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which prints:

```
[single] => Array
    (
        [name] => foo.txt
        [type] => text/html
        [tmp_name] => /path/to/tmp/php/qwqerqrq
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1621
    )

[multiple] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => bar.txt
                [1] => baz.txt
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => text/plain
                [1] => text/plain
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /path/to/tmp/php/vwvwrvwrv
                [1] => /path/to/tmp/php/wqerverhw
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 36976
                [1] => 58355
            )

    )
```

If your code is setup expecting the structure of a single file in `$_FILES`, you'll need to update it to work with the very different structure of a multi-file upload.

Comment: After adding brackets to the input element name my form doesn't work at all (no errors), just reloads after submitting.

Comment: Try another `var_dump` (or post your entire form). It comes through in an odd (to me) format. Also see that comment on php.net for a workaround if that's the issue.

Comment: Sorry! I discovered a notice message: **Array to string conversion in /.../submit-from-front.php on line 167**. This line is the `return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];`.

Comment: Checked with `var_dump`, now the $_FILES array include two files, but the mentioned 167 line also returns an error. I will check this later, now I must to go.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like what I'm describing. `foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {...` will not work with the multiple submit because the format of the POSTed object has changed. Inspect that `var_dump` and make sure you're looping over the correct array..