# What is the best way to handle Ajax image upload on front end?

Tags: images, ajax, uploads

I have been searching around for awhile but haven't found a solution yet. For this question, I like to get some general answers or resources for implementing AJAX image upload in front-end form.

Thank you.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11400/82166

Comment: @scriptonomy Thank you for the comment. I'm going to try if that's gonna solve my issue. Do you have any idea how to make that work with `on change` instead of clicking submit button tho?

Comment: $('#file-input').change(function (){ $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit(options);});